# how i can Convert $_POST in a array?

Tags: php, post

by using

```
print_r($_POST);
```

i am getting data something like this

```
Array ( [selected_friends] => {"0":"699712136","1":"1622040878","2":"100002980112267"})
```

how i can use it as array and put it into a array variable
like

```
$a[0] = 699712136;
$a[1] = 1622040878;
```

and so on.

Comment: `$a = json_decode( $_POST['selected_friends'], $assoc = true );`

Comment: @scibuff: It's a shame you didn't post it as an answer. Nicola did and he already got 4 upvotes. That could have been you! Don't post answers in comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do

```
$a = json_decode($_POST['selected_friends'], true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like JSON. Try json_decode()